# How to return number of views(ZLSwipeableViewSwif) like UITableview data source?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement , i cannot set number of views, i want to set only five view, which property i need to use before view is loading.
Library link [enter link description here](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift)

```
self.swipeableView.numberOfActiveView = 5;
self.swipeableView.discardViews()
self.swipeableView.loadViews()
```

I am trying with their demo application.

Comment: In this tuts, there are multiple cards based on array so you can define one another array with only 5 object so it will give you 5 cards. Have you try this?

Comment: In their demo 
var colors = ["Turquoise", "Green Sea", "Emerald", "Nephritis", "Peter River", "Belize Hole", "Amethyst", "Wisteria", "Wet Asphalt", "Midnight Blue", "Sun Flower", "Orange", "Carrot", "Pumpkin", "Alizarin", "Pomegranate", "Clouds", "Silver", "Concrete", "Asbestos"]

But its show  more than array count

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace your colors array with other array like,

Declare one more array below that color array,

```
var imgArray = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

Now find the color array from the view did load and replace it with imgArray like,

```
swipeableView.nextView = {
        if self.colorIndex < self.imgArray.count //self.colors.count
        {
            var cardFrame = CGRectMake(self.swipeableView.frame.origin.x, 0, self.swipeableView.frame.size.width, 250)
            var cardView = CardView(frame: cardFrame)
            var img : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: cardView.bounds)
            img.image = UIImage(named: self.imgArray[self.colorIndex])
            cardView.addSubview(img)
            self.colorIndex++

            ....
            ....

        }
```

This working fine at my end so hope this will help you.